use azurerm_virtual_machine with trusted_launch
Due to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6117, I must use azurerm_virtual_machine to create my intended machine.
Unfortunately, the image in use requires trusted launch, for which I could not find any configuration option.
Is this possible or am I forced to use az_api instead?

You can achieve this by using local-exec provisioner to execute Azure CLI commands to enable Trusted Launch after the VM creation at same run.

You can also use AzAPI provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-terraform#terraform-azapi-provider-resource-definition for creating VM with Trusted Launch

First one does not work :(

What about a second one? Is it working?

If you want, I will share the code using the first method

Please share the code for the first, yes.
I did (only relevant parts):
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
location   = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
name       = my-vm
resource_group_name              = my-rg
vm_size                          = "Standard_D${var.cores}ls_v5"
provisioner "local-exec" {
when = create
command = <<EOF
az account set --subscription ${var.subscription_id}
az vm update --resource-group my-rg --name my-vm --security-type TrustedLaunch --enable-secure-boot true --enable-vtpm true
EOF
}

As it seems not possible with azurerm, I ended up doing it with terraform_data.
As the image I'm using defines managed data disks, I had to extend the cleanup accordingly. My code looks like this:
resource "terraform_data" "vm" {
  input = {
    subscription_id     = var.subscription_id
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    vmname              = var.vm_name
    vm_size             = var.vm_size
    vm_username         = var.admin_username
    password            = var.admin_password
    nic_id              = azurerm_network_interface.main.id
    hostname            = random_string.hostname.result
    location            = var.location
    image_id            = var.image_id
    tags                = local.cli_tags
    identity            = join(" ", data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.main[*].id)
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = create
    command = <<EOF
az account set --subscription ${self.input.subscription_id}
az vm create --resource-group ${self.input.resource_group_name} --name ${self.input.vmname} --image ${self.input.image_id} --size ${self.input.vm_size} --security-type TrustedLaunch --enable-secure-boot true --enable-vtpm true --admin-username ${self.input.vm_username} --admin-password ${self.input.password} --os-disk-size-gb 128 --nics ${self.input.nic_id} --computer-name ${self.input.hostname} --nic-delete-option delete --os-disk-delete-option delete --location "${self.input.location}" --os-disk-caching ReadWrite --data-disk-caching ReadWrite --storage-sku Premium_LRS --assign-identity [system] ${self.input.identity} --tags ${self.input.tags}
EOF
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = <<EOF
az account set --subscription ${self.input.subscription_id}
ids=$(az vm show -d -g ${self.input.resource_group_name} -n ${self.input.vmname} --query "storageProfile.dataDisks[].managedDisk.id" | jq -r 'join(" ")')
az vm delete -g ${self.input.resource_group_name} -n ${self.input.vmname} --yes
az disk delete --ids $ids --yes
EOF
  }
}

locals {
  cli_tags = join(" ", [for k, v in var.tags : "${k}=\"${v}\""])
}

Beware that only the relevant code for the vm is posted and may required adaptations for specific needs. Additionally, the hostname is set randomly to prevent machines with the same name trying to join AAD. Also beware to add all inputs which should force a recreation of the resource.

Here is the Terraform script to create a Virtual Machine with Trusted Launch configuration using the azurerm module. For Azapi, refer to the MS Doc
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "venkat" {
  name     = "terraform1-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "venkat" {
  name                = "example-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.venkat ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "venkat" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.venkat.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.venkat ]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "venkat" {
  name                = "example-nic1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.venkat.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_subnet.venkat ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "venkat" {
  name                  = "venkat-machine-testvm2"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.venkat.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "terraformvenkat-vm-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
    sku       = "20_04-lts-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "P@ssw0rd1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "vm-deallocate1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
az vm deallocate --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name} --name ${azurerm_virtual_machine.venkat.name}
EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.venkat]
}

resource "null_resource" "vm-1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
az vm update --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name} --name ${azurerm_virtual_machine.venkat.name} --security-type TrustedLaunch
sleep 60
az vm start --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.venkat.name} --name ${azurerm_virtual_machine.venkat.name}
EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.vm-deallocate1]
}

Output:


I really appreciate your efforts - thanks! However, as said, this does not work for me as the (uppercase only for visibility) THE IMAGE IN USE REQUIRES TRUSTED LAUNCH.
In above example, azurerm_virtual_machine.venkat is never created but fails, so later steps are never executed.

Can you please share the error message that you are getting?

I just reran my code, as it's working fine for me, Here is the result

azure-arm: ERROR: -> BadRequest : The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type.

Are you using Gallery Image?

I'm 100% sure your code works just fine. I have >10 custom images of generalized VMs which had trusted launch set when the generalized images where created. So now using these images, trusted launch is required. The public gallery images don't have this restriction.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
